# Javassist: Generate "assert" statement

Tags: assert, javassist

I try to add an "assert" statement to a method.

But I get this exception:

Caused by: compile error: assert(boolean) not found in mypackage.MyClassThatIsInstrumented
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:716)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:681)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:156)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:45)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:241)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:329)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:350)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodBody(CodeGen.java:291)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileBody(Javac.java:222)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.setBody(CtBehavior.java:360)
    ... 30 more

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to implement the assertion as a conditional:

```
 if(Foo.class.desiredAssertionStatus() && expr) {
   throw new AssertionError();
 }
```

This is basically equivalent to

```
 assert expr;
```

Now it is a matter of how you would like to inject it. If you need to assert against the method parameters, you can use method.insertBefore(); if you're asserting the result, you can use method.insertAfter().

If the statement needs to be inserted into the method's body, somewhere in between the statements, then you can use [ExprEditor](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/expr/ExprEditor.html) to match the required statement where you want this new statement to be injected